# git-media and GitExtensions

Tags: git, git-extensions, git-media

Some of our projects contain binary files which should be within the version control system too (next to the source code files).

Up until now we've used Subversion and everything was fine, however, we want to move our repositories to Git now. As Git unfortunately has problems with binary files we've looked into [git-media](https://github.com/schacon/git-media) which is a very promising extension.

Our whole team makes use of the GitExtensions GUI-based tool, is there any possibility of git-media integration? E.g. after checking in a binary file the media files should be immediately synced, the same should happen after pulling data, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "Git unfortunately has problems with binary files"? The only "problem" that I'm aware of is that binary diffs aren't terribly useful, but this applies to Subversion as well. What problem are you trying to solve?